# How to generate a simple 2D terrain map

Tags: java, terrain

I am making simple 2D game in Java and need to generate a terrain map as a simple 2D `matrix` of `int` but don't know what algorithm to use.

I will visualise this `matrix` using grayscale.

[Example here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gFyE5.png)

What algorithm should I use to generate my terrain map?

Answer (score 2):

There are lots of different ways to do this.  You probably want to start with the "diamond - square" algorithm, which is easy to understand and produces pretty good terrain:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diamond-square_algorithm

Comment: Perlin Noise is another common algorithm for generating terrains.  It's more complicated than Diamond Square but it looks more natural and less like a fractal in my opinion.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Perlin_noise